# Horizontally and vertically center absolutely positioned element

Tags: html, css

Just as the title indicates, I'm trying to horizontally and vertically center an absolutely positioned element.  [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/1weNJYXgO0K4b7fRa6MZ) is a plunker of my attempt based on other posts I've found.  The goal is to have the red ALERT text to be centered within the outlined box.

And here is the CSS:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  bottom: 0;
  color: red;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/, https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%,-50%); right: auto; bottom: auto;`

Comment: @somethinghere: not working... http://plnkr.co/edit/gl9DLdrLJopMw1gP1oWt?p=preview

Comment: ```html,body { height : 100%; }```

Comment: @AllanRaquin: That doesn't work either.

Comment: It _is_ working, its just that your `.parent` class is useless. Because it has no height or contents (except something positioned `absolute`), the center of that box is 50% on the y axis and 0 on the X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try positioning absolute the parent (you have to set a height):

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h5s2cs3z/)

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    color: red;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 16px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things: for something to be centered, the parent container *needs* to have a height. Be it height created by other content, or simply a predefined height. I have removed your `.parent` and you will see the `.child` actually centering inside the container. Your container also needs a relative position (or any position property other than `static`), so the absolute centering is in relation to that element.

Lastly, we can use a simply technique to center your box by moving it 50% right, 50% down and then moving it back by half of its width and height. The moving back uses translation:

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  // We need the container we want to center in to have a positioned value
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">ALERT</div>
  <p>Item here</p>
  <p>Item here</p>
  <p>Item here</p>
  <p>Item here</p>
  <p>Item here</p>
  <p>Item here</p>
  <p>Item here</p>
  <p>Item here</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A neat thing with Html is that you can use percentiles instead of pixels to describe relativity. For example:

instead of using:

```
bottom: 250px;
```

you can use something like:

```
right: 43%;
```

using that along with calculated proportions, such as:

```
top:45%
bottom: 45%;
```

and setting the text height to 10%, you can have anything you want centered.

judging by your code you're already familiar with "auto" so I'll save you that song and dance.